# Is there a reality capture parameter to request the desired number of vertices?

Tags: autodesk-forge, point-clouds, vertices, autodesk-realitycapture

In the previous reality capture system users could set a parameter which would determine the resolution of the output models.   I want to wind up with models about 100-150K vertices.  Is there a setting that allows me to request the modeler to keep the number of generated vertices within some bounds, somewhere in the forge API?

Answer (score 0):

The vertex/triangle decimation is usually, what can be called "subjective" task, which can also explain why there are so many optimization algorithms in the wild.

One type of optimization you would need and expect for "organic" models, and totally different one for an architectural building.

The Reality Capture API provides you only with raw Hi-Res results, avoiding "opionated" optimizations. This should be considered just as a step in automation pipeline.
Another step, would be, upon receiving, to automatically optimize the resulted mesh based on set of settings you need.

One of these steps could be [Design Automation for 3ds Max](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/3dsmax/), where you feed a model and using the [ProOptimizer Modifier](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/3DSMax-Modifiers/files/GUID-109C880F-181B-4067-91F0-B4EF79639FB3-htm.html) within 3ds Max, you output the mesh with needed detail. A sample of this step, can be found here: https://forge-showroom.autodesk.io/post/prooptimizer.

There are also numerous opensource solutions which should help you cover this post-processing step.